# SwiftUI CloudKit Sharing Permissions Not As Expected

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, cloudkit

I'm struggling mightily with permissions on a UICloudSharingController. I have a SwiftUI
application using Core Data and CloudKit. The application works great - all data on
all devices sync'd with the iCloud. I want to include the option for the user to share
records with others. The sharing also works except for my efforts to control the
permissions programmatically. Ideally, I would like all shares to be with access
.allowPrivate only and then include a switch that sets permission to .allowReadOnly
or .allowReadWrite.

When the share sheet is presented with no permission limitations in the code and the user taps
Share Options, then chooses View Only, the share sheet correctly shows this choice
and says "Invited people can view only".

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, once "Share with more people" is tapped
the permission is reset to "Only invited people can edit".

[image]

If the user then taps that
link and again taps "view only" the permission again changes to "Only invited people
can view".

[image]

Tapping an invitee and sending the message results in the correct sharing
where the user had Read Only access. This is obviously a very poor user experience.

Apple docs, in several places say access and permissions can be controlled with an array
of desired permissions, but this is not working for me. Clearly, I'm misunderstanding something.

[image]

Here is my controller:

```
struct CloudSharingView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    //a switch sets this property
    @AppStorage("shareReadOnly") var shareReadOnly: Bool = true

    let share: CKShare
    let container: CKContainer
    //this is my Core Data Entity
    let recipe: Recipe

    func makeCoordinator() -> CloudSharingCoordinator {
        CloudSharingCoordinator(recipe: recipe)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UICloudSharingController {
        share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = recipe.rName
    
        let controller = UICloudSharingController(share: share, container: container)

        //this does not help
        //controller.availablePermissions = [.allowPrivate, .allowReadOnly]
        
        //this is what I want, but it does not work either
        /*
        if shareReadOnly {
            controller.availablePermissions = [.allowPrivate, .allowReadOnly]
        } else {
            controller.availablePermissions = [.allowPrivate, .allowReadWrite]
        }
        */

        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator

        return controller
    }//make

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UICloudSharingController, context: Context) {
        print("in update shareReadOnly is \(shareReadOnly.description)")
    }//update
}

final class CloudSharingCoordinator: NSObject, UICloudSharingControllerDelegate {
    let stack = CoreDataStack.shared
    let recipe: Recipe
    init(recipe: Recipe) {
        self.recipe = recipe
    }

    func itemTitle(for csc: UICloudSharingController) -> String? {
        recipe.rName
    }

    func cloudSharingController(_ csc: UICloudSharingController, failedToSaveShareWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to save share: \(error)")
    }

    func cloudSharingControllerDidSaveShare(_ csc: UICloudSharingController) {
        print("Saved the share")
    }

    func cloudSharingControllerDidStopSharing(_ csc: UICloudSharingController) {
        if !stack.isOwner(object: recipe) {
            stack.delete(recipe)
        }
    }
}//coordinator
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 14.2 iOS 16.2

Comment: Are you using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer?

Comment: Yes. Apple has acknowledged that this is a bug. I filed a Feedback report. Feedback ID: FB11941000

Comment: Hi @JohnSF - have you heard anything regarding your FB lately?

Comment: Hello phiredrop. No, I ended up publishing with user instructions on how to perform the shares. I have not revisited the issue with Xcode 15 and iOS 17. That would be good to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIViewControllerRepresentable` is not implemented correctly. However, there is actually already `ShareLink` in SwiftUI that provides this feature. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sharedwithyou/adding_shared_content_collaboration_to_your_app) for sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the ShareLink tip. I will check out ShareLink. It would be a great deal more helpful if you would explain why you believe the UIViewControllerRepresentable is not implemented correctly.

Comment: You need a custom `UIViewController` and an `@Binding var isPresented: Bool` in the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and in the `updateUIViewController` you need to present or dismiss a `UICloudSharingController` depending on the value of `isPresented`. You also need to do some work to implement 2-way binding of the share property.